# contact exists in contacts

Tags: android

I have phone number. Is there any way to check whether the phone number exists in contacts database in the device or not? Depending on that I need have move further in my app. Please suggest or if any one can have sample code snippet please provide.

The below is the code I wrote:

```
public boolean contactExists(Activity _activity, String number) {
    String[] mPhoneNumberProjection = { PhoneLookup._ID, PhoneLookup.NUMBER, PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME };
    Cursor cur = _activity.getContentResolver().query(number, mPhoneNumberProjection, null, null, null);
    try {
        if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
            return true;
        }
    } finally {
        if (cur != null)
            cur.close();
    }
    return false;
}// contactExists
```

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: hi @user1306412 in my case this function always return false, i do as answeres,you give me some suggestion in it ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
public boolean contactExists(Activity _activity, String number) {
    if (number != null) {
        Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(number));
        String[] mPhoneNumberProjection = { PhoneLookup._ID, PhoneLookup.NUMBER, PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME };
        Cursor cur = _activity.getContentResolver().query(lookupUri, mPhoneNumberProjection, null, null, null);
        try {
            if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
                return true;
            }
        } finally {
            if (cur != null)
                cur.close();
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}// contactExists
```

Handled nullpointer exception.

Comment: heloo @Ishu my condition always gone on false, i checked if it reurn true i insert record otherwise not but it all time return false if not duplicate then also

Comment: @NiravMehta - I suggest that you don't go copying other peoples' code without trying to understand it.

Comment: @Ishu - dealing with a null argument like that is a bad idea.  It is better to let the NPE happen, and then when it does track down where / why you are calling `contactExists` with a `null` argument.  It is always better to fix the root cause bug than to hide it.

Comment: How can I check contact by _ID? This code always returns `false` if parameter `number` assigned as _ID.

Answer (score 3):

A minor change in your code ::
You need to have lookupUri..

```
public boolean contactExists(Activity _activity, String number) {
    Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(number));
    String[] mPhoneNumberProjection = { PhoneLookup._ID, PhoneLookup.NUMBER, PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME };
    Cursor cur = _activity.getContentResolver().query(lookupUri, mPhoneNumberProjection, null, null, null);
    try {
        if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
            return true;
        }
    } finally {
        if (cur != null)
            cur.close();
    }
    return false;
}// contactExists
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code above on an ice cream device (SIII) and it didnt work
so after some search i ended up creating this method (which is working nicely )

```
    private boolean isContact(String incommingNumber) {
        Cursor cursor =null;
        String name = null;
        try {
            Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(incommingNumber));
             cursor = MainService.this.getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[] { PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME }, null, null, null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
            }
        } finally {
            if(cursor!=null){
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
        return Util.hasValue(name);
    }
```